# AWS Lambda - where is the Triggers tab?

Tags: aws-lambda

Where has the triggers tab gone in AWS Lambda?

E.g. as described here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/lambda-edge-add-triggers-lam-console.html

With my tested, versioned Lambda function here:
https://console.aws.amazon.com/lambda/home?region=us-east-1#/functions/Canary/versions/1?tab=graph

I don't see a Triggers tab.

Answer (score 0):

you have the trigger list on the left side of the diagram add your triggers there:

[image]

btw thats "add triggers from the list to the left" in spanish.